# Why should the SSID be the same when installing multiple access points?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, ssid

I understand that the best practice for installation of multiple wireless access points (in a home environment for example) is to give them the same SSID, but *why* is this the case?  Why not give them different SSIDs, one benefit of which is always knowing exactly who you are talking to.  When moving around, won't most wireless clients hop from access to access point anyway once they remember them?

Comment: Just remember to write down the MACs of the APs, otherwise, the day one breaks down, it will be difficult to identify the faulty one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different SSID's = different WiFi networks, and the OS will attempt to hang on to their current network as long as possible, regardless if there's another known network closer by.

If the SSIDs are the same, then the OS and adapters (if they support it) can roam from one AP to the next depending on things like signal strength, AP preferences, on-demand depending on the intelligence within the AP points, etc.

Most decent WiFi adapters will tell you (via a utility or alike) what the MAC of the current AP it's connected to is, so you can use that to discern which AP you are currently attached to.